# Small solar panel chip to charge a LiPo

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, boost, charger, panel

I've found this small solar panel:

https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/anysolar-ltd/KXOB25-02X8F-TB/9990458

I see that output can go up to 4.5v and 5mA . That's sounds huge for me BUT because I never worked with solar panels so I don't know if this is standard or maybe just laboratory values.

I'd like to use this panel to charge a small 3.7v 100mAh LiPo for an outdoor application or, if not possible, to reduce buttery power consumption.

What is the simplest and most efficient way? (even if possible)

Should I use a switch boost ( but as found efficiency is about 65% ) to my small battery charger that works at 5V?

Should I connect it directly to electronics with a diode?

Is there specialized ICs that does this?

Comment: You can get some guidelines here: https://www.itekenergy.com/how-to/charging-a-lipo-battery-with-a-solar-panel/